# Fake Proof: $a^n = 1$ f or all nonnegative integers $n$

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

> Find the flaw with the following "proof" that $a^n = 1$ for all nonnegative integers $n$, whenever $a$ is a nonzero real number.
>
> *Basis Step*: $a^0 = 1$ is true by definitino of $a^0$.
>
> *Inductive Step*: Assume that $a^j = 1$ for all nonnegative integers $j$ with $j \leq k$. Then note that
>   $$
>   a^{k+1} = \frac{a^k \cdot a^k}{a^{k-1}} = \frac{1 \cdot 1}{1} = 1
> $$

Where is the flaw in the above proof? My answer is that the basis step needs to iterate nonnegative integers beyond $0$, like $1$, $2$, etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint:  write out what this looks like for $k=0$.  That is, try to use this principle to demonstrate that $a^1=1$.

Comment: In your inductive step you're using $a^{k-1}=a^k=1$, but at the base case you only know $a^0=1$ and not $a^1=1$ (or not $a^{-1}=1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a^1=\cfrac {a^0\cdot a^0}{a^{-1}}$ and your hypothesis doesn't cover the case of $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

The inductive step requires $k\geq1$, because of the denominator (you are using that $a^{-1}=1$, which forces $a=1$). But you want to start your induction at $k=0$. So the base step and the inductive step are not connected.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the induction fails on the first step, since when you only have $k = 0$, you cannot make use of $a^{k-1} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

2 things wrong:

1)You can not assume anything more in your induction step than was shown in the base step.

In here you are assuming that k-1 is also nonnegative.  That is *not* the case for k = 0 so we can not assume that.

2) Even more basic.  When you assume a base step is true for k, you can not assume you have shown it is true for all j <= k.  You can only assume it is true for k and *only* k.  This is important if the inductive step requires not just k but k- 1, then your base step must not merely show for k = 1 (or zero) but for k = 0 (or negative 1) as well.  Or equivalently for k=1 and k = 2.

If you do show for both k =1 and k=2, your induction *is* sound.

====

This reminds me of the proof that all the marbles in a bag of marbles are the same color.

Base case: n = 1. All the marbles in a bag  of just one marble are same color.  (Because there is only 1 marble so there can't be more than 1 color.)

Inductive case:  Assume all the marbles in a bag of n marbles are the same color.  Take a bag of n + 1 marble.  Take a marble out.  You now have a bag of n marbles.  Therefore they are all the same color.  Remove one of these marbles.  Put the original marble you removed back in.  You have a bag of n marbles so they are all the same color.  No return the 2nd marble.  It was the same color so now all the marbles in the bag of n+1 marbles are the same color.

Therefore by induction all the marbles in any size bag of marbles are the same color.